# Dynamically loading external javascript resources in Splash HTTP rendering service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrapy-splash

I'm currently using [Splash HTTP API](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as a headless browser to render request.
I'm using the endpoint **render.html** with **js_source**  which allows the evaluation of custom Javascript code within the page context, after the page finishes loading, and before the page is rendered.

I'm in need of making additional requests to external resources, such as loading **jQuery** after the page is loaded.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

The problem is that by doing such, the objects do not become available within the page context. The script does appear to be added within the HEAD element of the final rendered HTML source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

I tried setting a callback using both methods described below to make sure the script is loaded before accessing any of **jQuery**'s methods. But the callback fails to be invoked in both scenarios.

```
script.onreadystatechange = callback;
script.onload = callback;
```

Running the aforementioned scripts in **Chrome**'s console does what I require and immediately makes the jQuery resource available within the page context.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can make it work with `js_source`, but as a feature `js_source` is quite limited; [/execute](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#execute) endpoint and a custom Lua script are much more versatile, and often easier to use:

```
function main(splash)
    splash:autoload("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(1.0))
    splash:runjs(splash.args.js_source)
    return splash:html()
end
```

^^ this script emulates render.html endpoint, but preloads jQuery; it  supports 'url' and 'js_source' arguments and hardcodes 'wait' to 1.0.

Comment: I'm currently making Splash requests from a Python context. I wouldn't add additional dependencies like supporting Lua scripting. Injecting javascript code that would evaluate before rendering the page would have been what I was looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by additional dependencies? Are you installing Splash using Docker? If so, it already supports Lua scripts - see "lua_source" argument to /execute endpoint. You don't need Lua installed on a client.

Comment: What I meant with additional dependencies is that I wouldn't want to support Lua scripting if it isn't truly required. The Lua scripts evaluate the js in the same way, the only difference is that the resources are downloaded externally, which doesn't work in my case. In my current implementation I need to send some additional requests from the browser context after the page loads to save some tokens on the page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by "resources are downloaded externally"? And why can't you send these additional requests from the browser context using this Lua script executed on Splash side?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the **autoload** command from **/execute** endpoint, downloads the resources asynchronously through a **HTTP GET** in Python, https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/blob/master/splash/qtrender_lua.py#L898, then casually evaluates the js in a similar fashion as **js_source** does. https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/blob/master/splash/browser_tab.py#L655

So there is no way of adding/downloading external resources from within the browser context, as you would usually do with a **HTML** script resource
:(

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue, it looks like Splash doesn't re-evaluate the DOM upon changes, the thing that worked for me was to make a synchronous **XMLHttpRequest** to the resource and the evaluate the response:

```
src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js";

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', src, false);
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
    eval(request.responseText);
};
```